# Webserver and permissions - two users having rights to modify specific (but not all) files

Tags: nginx, permissions, chmod, chown

So,the typical situation is like that: webserver (in this case nginx) works under the www-data user.

And then there is also 'konrad' user, which is just an ordinary user.

And now, the whole website (/var/www/html/cool-site) has the owner: konrad, and group: www-data.

Files are mostly 750.

And that is fine (I guess). But... now I have a situation, where another user comes in. Lets call him 'mike'. And now, what I want to achieve, is that he wants to be able to modify files owned by me, and I want to be able to modify files owned by him.

Or, better yet - I, as an admin, would like to decide, for every directory(?), file(?) that only *I* (konrad) or only him (mike) or both of us, can do the changes.

Obviously, we both should have the right to view the files and browse the directories.

What I was thinking about is this: create yet another group, like 'common'. Add 'www-data' user to this group. Add both of us (konrad and mike) to this group. And whenever I (or mike) decide that we both should have write access to this dir/file, we would chown it to this group, and the permissions would allow writing there.
Then I realized that in this scenario, www-data would have write access to these directories/files.

So I'm stuck. I believe there is a solution, but I can't think of anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another group, as you suggested, but don't add `www-data` to this group.

Leave all permissions as they are, and add an **extended permission** for the files/directores you want to be modifiable by `common` group:

```
setfacl -m g:common:rw filename ...
```

You can read more in `man setfacl`.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try, although I have never worked with ACL, but I hope I'll handle it :) I have to :)